# Where can I find data related to foreign remittances?

Tags: micro-data

I am doing research related to remittances, where can i find a good source of data?

Thanks

Comment: What sort of data? Please be specific.

Comment: You can for instance specify your needs (i) household survey or aggregate data? (2) the type of frequency? (3) information on the recipient or/and sending country? etc...

Answer (score 1):

In the [World Bank](http://www.worldbank.org/en/topic/migrationremittancesdiasporaissues/brief/migration-remittances-data) website you can find data on remittances such as

- Annual and Monthly Remittance Flows to Selected Countries,
- Bilateral Remittances Matrices,

and

- Household survey data on migration and remittances.